# PHP Laravel Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am developing a feature for an app using Laravel, and I am coming across this weird error that I can't figure out. I have the following code as a helper function to my controller, which was working just fine before I added a call to the following function:

```
protected function f($p){

    $cIds = $cs->select('cs.id')->get();

    $cs = DB::table('cs')
            ->select('cs.id')
            ->join('pucs', 'cs.id', '=', 'pucs.c_id')
            ->where('pucs.p_id', '=', (string)$p->id)
            ->whereIn('cs.id', $cIds)->lists('cs.id');
    return $cs;
}
```

where `pucs` has a foreign key to `cs` and a column called `p_id`, and I only want to return rows where `p_id = $p->id`. `$p` is the result of a previous query, and `$p->id` is an int (I think?). When I open the page on my website, I get the following error:

> Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()

Does anyone have any insight as to what might be causing this problem? My initial thought was that `$p->id` was an int and that was causing the problem, so I cast it to a string using the `(string)` operator, as well as trying `strval($p->id)`. I'm out of ideas.

UPDATE: using pluck('cs.id') gives the same error. I thought the issue might have been (string)$p->id, but when I comment out ->where('pucs.p_id', '=', (string)$p->id) I still get the same issue. For reference, I have a very similar line of code in the same helper file:

```
$bIds = $bs->select('bs.id')->get();
$bs = DB::table('bs')
    ->whereIn('bs.id', $bIds)->lists('bs.id');
```

I'm pretty sure it was working before, even while I was getting errors on the earlier piece of code, but now it's not working either.

Anyway, the reason I'm doing this is because I have these awkward tables that have been joined and unioned with other tables, and then selected a subset of cs.id (or bs.id) from that, and I want just the result of the original tables. Also, I was getting some weird errors because MYSQL apparently has a problem sorting unioned tables by id?

Comment: I hate to be so forward... but is the error message not *super* clear? You called `->lists()`, and that call is "Missing argument 1".

Comment: use `pluck` instead of `lists`. but also yeah I don't get the point of calling lists or pluck without an argument

Comment: So I was refactoring the code for posting on here, and that wasn't even the error I wanted to fix haha. I updated the question.

Comment: `f($p){}` See the extra `}`

Answer (score 3):

When using `lists()`, you need to pass in the name of the key you want the values for. Normally you would call `get()` here instead of `lists()`, but if you call `lists('cs.id')` then you should get an array of the matching cs.id's.

Comment: So I was refactoring the code for posting on here, and that wasn't even the error I wanted to fix haha. I updated the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you changed about the question? I still see the same "Missing argument 1" error